# How to get height of AlertDialog on Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I use below code to show a dialog:

```
private AlertDialog MyDialog;
public void adddialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder MyBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    MyBuilder.setTitle("Title")
    MyBuilder .setView(ListView);
    MyDialog = MyBuilder.create();
}
```

The ListView may un-fix rows.
But I want to get the MyDialog's height.
How can I do to get it?

Comment: use activity as dialog then you height and width is same as device screen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the `ListView` visible height, you need to get height of `one row` of the list and multiply by the number of elements ( which are presently visible).

Something like this.

```
        Adapter ListAdapter = listview.getAdapter();
        View mView  = ListAdapter.getView(0, null, listview);
        mView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), 
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
        int requiredHeight = listview.getChildCount() * mView.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getHeight() of the listView Object instead of getting height of dialog.

Comment: But it not contain the title and the padding of dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the height, it means Information about how tall the view wants to be..
SO maybe you can try like this:
You can get the height with:

```
     int height = MyDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();
```

Also, you can set the height With:

```
     MyDialog.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);
```

Notice: all method should be called after `MyDialog.show();`

Comment: I add this after MyDialog.show().  But I use this method, I get height = -2.

Comment: try this one: MyDialog.getWindow().getDecorView().getHeight();